# Adding bits cause wrong number when first byte is zero

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I'm combining 8-bit integers to a 32-bit integer. When the first byte is 0, python for some reason interprets it as a negative number.

```
a = 0
b = -35
c = 64
d = 0
res = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | c << 8 | d   # res = -2277376 instead of 14499840
```

I need res to be 14499840 and not -2277376. Any way I can force python not to ignore the first 8 bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not because of `a` being zero, but it's because **b is negative**:

```
>>> res = (a << 24) | (b << 16) | c << 8 | d
>>> res
-2277376
>>> b << 16
-2293760
```

So if the bytes can be negative you need to make them positive first by masking with 0xFF:

```
res = ((a & 0xFF) << 24) | ((b & 0xFF) << 16) | ((c & 0xFF) << 8) | (d & 0xFF)
```

Or better read the input as unsigned bytes instead of signed

Comment: Thanks :) Your solution works. I'll try to check if I can treat all as unsigned. Cheers

Comment: @Elvisboy you can always (and should) treat all but the top byte of an integer as unsigned. If the integer overall is supposed to be signed, then only `a` would be signed.